# Hierarchy from Flat Data

Tags: c#, hierarchy

I have an employee class that has an employeeId (int), parent(int) and children property `List<Employee>`. I get the employee list from the database in the correct order **and now need to build the hierarchy**, but I am failing miserably...I know this is programming 101, but I am having a hard time with it.

```
public class Employee
{
  public int EmployeeId { get; set;}
  public int ParentId;{ get; set;}
  public List<Employee> Children; { get; set;}

}
```

Data Example

```
EmployeeId, ManagerId
1, 0 //no one
2, 1
3, 1
4, 2
5, 2
6, 3
7, 3
```

Comment: What have you tried in order to build the hierarchy? Can you post your code and the issues you are having?

Comment: What's your question? What do the employee's Children have to do with anything?

Comment: @Qwertie - he wants to know how to populate the correct hierarchy in C# as it is stored in the database.

Comment: @Oded, I tried keeping track of the parentId and adding Children if the parent id is the same as the current item's parent id, but then failed when going to level 2+.

Comment: @Qwertie, i changed question to bold.

Comment: @12345 - did you sort the records by `ManagerId`?

Comment: @Oded - Yes, the result is sorted. I've done this before, just can't find the src. I am aware there may be some recursion involved (maybe not since it is sorted...) but i've spent a while trying to figure this out...frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by creating a list of all the employee objects and setting the `EmployeeId` and `ParentId` properties. If you also put them in a dictionary, keyed by `EmployeeId`, you can retrieve the parent of each afterward to add to the `Children` collection:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
Dictionary<int,Employee> dict = new Dictionary<int,Employee>();

foreach(result from database query)
{
   Employee employee = new Employee();
   employee.EmployeeId = result["EmployeeId"];
   employee.ParentId = result["ParentId"];
   employees.Add(employee);
   dict.Add(employee.EmployeeId, employee);
}

foreach(Employee e in employees)
{ 
  dict[e.ParentId].Children.Add(e);
}
```

Comment: the only problem is my dictionary ends up having all the items PLUS the hierarchical data. So if my list from the db contains 13 items, I end up with 13 items and then some of the items have children...instead of say 4 items with 9 children. Does that make sense?

Comment: The dictionary is only needed for looking up the ParentId to add to the Children collection. Once the hieracrhy is constructed, you can forget about the dictionary altogether.

If you just want the roots of the hierarchies then just keep a reference to each of the top-level employees and you can access the rest via the Children collections.

Comment: That makes sense, but how do I know which are the top level parents in hierarchy?

Comment: If all top-level employees have a ParentId of zero, then select those when iterating through the employees list, e.g., `if (e.ParentId==0) topLevelEmployees.Add(e);`

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Employee> allEmployees = new List<Employee>();
allEmployees.AddRange(LoadAllEmployees()); // pull from DB in flat format    
foreach (var employee in allEmployees)
{
  employee.Children = allEmployees.Where(e => e.ParentId == employee.EmployeeId).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i got inspiration from this article a while ago (i had to change it slightly to suit my purposes). It basically builds a hierarchical structure to the n'th degree.

Might be useful, even if only to discount its approach in your own case :-)

http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET23&Lang=EN